# Friendly URLs with mod_rewrite - how?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

My blog URLs look like this `/blog/?action=viewArticle&articleId=2`

I want them to look more like this: `/blog/name-of-article`

I've Googled, read a number of topics here on Stackoverflow, tried tweaking my .htaccess file, but nothing's working.

I'm not well versed on .htaccess or mod_rewrite tactics, and I'm not one to ask for help unless I really get stuck, so.... Help! :-)

Thanks!

Comment: What content management system are you using? Is it WordPress, something else, or did you code your own blog?

Comment: It won't be possible to implement what you want with just mod_rewrite.   That module can rewrite `/blog/name-of-article` to `/blog/?action=view&articleName=name-of-article` but it can't translate names into IDs, your blog software has to handle that.   mod_rewrite also won't change the links in your pages to make them into the friendly version, again your blog software will have to do that.

Comment: I coded my own blog, with some help from a friend who's no longer available to help. I don't necessarily need to be handed the exact code I need, but point me in the right direction would help immensely. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)